# Shoutcast URL does not stream on JPlayer, but does on another flash player?

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming, jplayer, shoutcast, internet-radio

I'm trying to stream http://gwradio.serverroom.us:4142/;stream.mp3 using JPlayer, but nothing happens when I try to play the stream.

Here's a test of the JPlayer code that has been confirmed to play other streams

```
var stream = {
    title: "WRGW TEST",
    mp3: "http://gwradio.serverroom.us:4142/;stream.mp3"
},
ready = false;

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        ready = true;
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
    },
    pause: function() {
        $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");
    },
    error: function(event) {
        if(ready && event.jPlayer.error.type === $.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {
            // Setup the media stream again and play it.
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
        }
    },
    swfPath: "../dist/jplayer",
    supplied: "mp3",
    preload: "none",
    wmode: "window",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    keyEnabled: true
});


$("#jplayer_inspector").jPlayerInspector({jPlayer:$("#jquery_jplayer_1")});
```

Here is the same URL working with another flash player: http://www.ep.gwradio.com/

Where's the beef? Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved - the issue was the server version of Shoutcast being used. Updating the server version fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your stream is served via SHOUTcast which does not send standards-compliant HTTP responses.  jPlayer will use native HTML5 audio in your browser, as well as Flash, to play your audio.  Your other player likely has hacks in place needed to support SHOUTcast-style streams.

You can use something like Icecast which follows HTTP specs more closely.